# activity unable to start Fragment and unable to show layout related to this. ending with null pointer

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I am following a book example but the following code is unable to start the`CrimeFragment()` fragment. Nothing appear on screen. `Activity` code is the following:

**CrimeActivity.java**

```
package com.example.simerpreetjassal.criminalintent;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;

public class CrimeActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_crime);
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.framgment_container);
        if(fragment==null) {
            fragment = new CrimeFragment();
            (fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.framgment_container, fragment)).commit();
        }

    }
}
```

Layout for upper activity. The file name is content_crime.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/framgment_container"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" />
```

Fragment code is the following. It is unable to show layout related to this and getting a null pointer exception on the edittext (mTittleField). How can I fix the mTittleField to get rid of the null pointer exception.

**CrimeFragment.java**

```
package com.example.simerpreetjassal.criminalintent;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class CrimeFragment extends Fragment {
    private Crime mCrime;
    private EditText mTittleField;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mCrime = new Crime();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crime, container, false);
        mTittleField = (EditText) v.findViewById((R.id.crime_title));
        mTittleField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
        return v;

    }
}
```

Layout related to this. File name is crime_fragment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/crime_title_hint"
        android:id="@+id/crime_title"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Logcat**

```
07-28 11:27:09.056 3083-3083/com.example.simerpreetjassal.criminalintent W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.simerpreetjassal.criminalintent-1/lib/x86
07-28 11:27:09.187 3083-3083/com.example.simerpreetjassal.criminalintent W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.simerpreetjassal.criminalintent-1/lib/x86
07-28 11:27:09.309 3083-3083/com.example.simerpreetjassal.criminalintent D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
07-28 11:27:09.310 3083-3083/com.example.simerpreetjassal.criminalintent E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.simerpreetjassal.criminalintent, PID: 3083
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.simerpreetjassal.criminalintent/com.example.simerpreetjassal.criminalintent.CrimeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.addTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.addTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.simerpreetjassal.criminalintent.CrimeFragment.onCreateView(CrimeFragment.java:26)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:330)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:547)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1237)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6253)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
    07-28 11:27:10.147 3083-3089/com.example.simerpreetjassal.criminalintent W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.535ms
```

Comment: Post the stacktrace/logcat

Comment: whats the layout of your activity?

Comment: whats the file name of the layout you provided?

Comment: lalongoo i updated my question. i have added logcat now and file names. more content of log is on right side so sroll to right to see the content of logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the xml layout file is not the same you are referring to in the `onCreateView()` of your fragment.

Your fragment layout xml file is `crime_fragment.xml` and the layout you are referring to from your Java code is `fragment_crime.xml` (through the `R` class).

Same for your `Activity`, it refers to a wrong layout `R.layout.activity_crime` when you layout xml file is `content_crime.xml`

Replace the `setContentView()` line of your Activity's `onCreate()` method with this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.content_crime);
```

Comment: thanks it works.but it still giving null pointer exception for mTittleField

Comment: yes i did. but still erroring out for null pointer exception for mTittleField